# Not filterable by stage at subscribe Azure DevOps pipeline in Microsoft Teams

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, microsoft-teams

I have installed Azure DevOps plug-in in Microsoft Teams. I want subscribe to a pipeline, so I write *Azure pipelines subscriptions* on the line. Afterwards List of subscribtions appears I choose Add subscription. Then I choose Release Deployment Completed and when it comes to Stage name (choose filters) I can only see the possibility [Any] . Why I don't see all the ones stages I use and I can't choose one when I use them in release pipelines ?[image]

Maybe I can try subscribe each individual pipeline by its url but this is approximately 60 individual requests. So subscribe to a whole project is better option for me.